# Authentication popup is not approved on page.authentication

Tags: puppeteer, adfs

I'm trying to perform web crawling on a website using Azure Functions on Linux. The website requires authentication from ADFS, so I need to log in. Specifically, when accessing the website, a Windows authentication popup appears, asking for a username and password. I want to handle this authentication using page.auth(page.authenticate({'username':'XXXX', 'password': 'XXXX'});), but it seems to be returning a 401 response (the username and password are correct). Is there a correct way to use page.authenticate for this purpose? If there are any other methods, please let me know.

I'm also using the headless: true setting. Could this be related to the 401 response? I haven't confirmed it yet because it's difficult to test with headless: false.

I have tested the process both with and without page.authenticate, and in both cases, I received a 401 response.

Here's an example
The site is private and cannot be provided. We could not find a site with a similar environment.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--disable-gpu',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--no-first-run',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--no-zygote',
        '--single-process'],
        headless: true,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.authenticate({'username':'XXXX', 'password': 'XXXX'});
    await page.goto("https://www.xxxxxxx.com");

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: It's basically impossible to help without the site and a [mcve] of your code. Thanks.